# Convert coordinates in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, referencing

I am trying to convert the coordinates given below. These coordinates have been provided to me with the given information: 'All co-ordinates are in Metres, Based upon International Spheroid, European Datum 1950 (ED50), Transverse Mercator, Central Meridian 3 E'.

[image]

When I save these co ordinates as a .csv file and upload into ArcGIS to Display XY Data so I can try convert, it wont let me pick eastings and northings in order to plot them, the only option shown is 'Point' (as seen below).

[image]

My goal is to convert these co ordinates from ED50 3 E into WGS84

Comment: It's most likely ED 1950 UTM zone 31 North, 23031.

Answer (score 1):

Mind the language settings of your ArcGIS and how the csv is saved. It is possible that your program does not recognise the Easting and Northing columns as numbers, but as text instead, and therefore they are not shown. Often this has something to do with the use of points and commas.
Your point columns is definitely a number column and is therefore given as an option.

You could also try to change the coordinate system of your "convert X and Y", because it is looking for WGS84 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comment above - just take out the commas - ArcGIS thinks that those columns are strings not numbers. I always double check in excel, formatting the columns specifically to be numbers, then exporting as a .csv, and then finally importing to ArcGIS.

Make sure that you input coord system matches the metadata you were provided, i.e. under description it should say something like "European Datum 1950, etc." - I'm not familiar with that coord system but you need to find/select it on import.